# Uninstalling complete GAE package

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

I installed GAE (selecting Java) on my Mac (OSX Mavericks). Now I don't want it any more, but it's installed itself all over my hard drive, and there is no obvious way of removing it.

I've found other similar requests, but I don't appear to have GoogleAppEngineLauncher on my system at all (I've searched).

Is there a method to simply remove the AppEngine entirely?

Comment: What do you mean by "I installed GAE"? What exactly did you install?

Comment: I followed the instructions in step 4 here:
https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.144058357.1122720462.1401750894

specifically "curl sdk.cloud.google.com | bash"

Comment: (I had the Java box selected, not the default Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean App Engine Java SDK, you can simply delete the folder with this SDK.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but won't that leave invalid references? It seems like my machine now runs parts of the SDK/framework at boot...

Comment: Post proof of such boot refs

Comment: App Engine SDK is just a collection of classes that a compiler needs when you write Java code that you plan to deploy to App Engine. It does not "install" anything on your computer.

Comment: You probably also installed Apache server. I don't know if it runs on startup. Google "uninstall Apache mac OS" if you want to remove it.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate you taking the time to help someone out who's clearly out of their depth ;)

Comment: Don't worry, it always feels that way at first. And you can simply accept an answer - that's a way to say thank you on StackOverflow.